# send data from html field(Not Form) using AJAX to python cgi

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I am trying to solve a problem, where I am suppose to send data using programmatic form which is not to use the form field itself to a backend python cgi script. However, I have no idea how to receive that text using python. With form I could use
`"form = cgi.FieldStorage()"`. However, for now, I am trying to send the data using `"XMLHttpRequest.send()"` but again i don't know how to catch this data from the python cgi script. So basically in here, I am having two issues. So far, in the following code, I am trying to get input value using JS and trying to create HTTPRequest to send over to a python script. But the output results in an error which is caught in the exception `"Request Failed"`

#Update: I was able to fix it. If anyone ever needs it. I will keep the post.

//This is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Login(Async)</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1> Please Login </h1>
    <label for="userName"> User Name </label><br>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User"><br>
    <label for="userName"> Password </label><br>
    <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="callCheckPass()"> Login </button>
    <p id="contentArea"> </p>
    
</body>
    <script>
        
        function callCheckPass(){
            asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            try{
                asyncRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", stateChange, false);
                asyncRequest.open("POST", "checkpass.py", true);
                asyncRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                asyncRequest.send("username=" + document.getElementById("username").value + "&" + "pwd="+ 
                                    + document.getElementById("pwd").value);
            }catch(exception){
                alert("Request Failed !!!");
            }
        }

        function stateChange(){
            if(asyncRequest.readyState == 4 && asyncRequest.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML = asyncRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        
    </script>
</html>
```

//This is the python script // I am not sure how to catch HTTPRequest in python.

```
#!C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe
import cgi, cgitb 
cgitb.enable() 

#instance of Field Storage
data = cgi.FieldStorage()

#get data from fields.
username = data.getvalue('username')

print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("<html>")
print("<head><title> Test </title> </head>")
print("<body> <h1> Input: %s </h1> </body>"%(username))
print("</html>")
```

[image]

Comment: It appears that you are masking what should be valuable error information by catching the exception thrown by the client's request, but then not doing anything with the exception.  Rather than displaying `"Request Failed !!!"`, how about displaying the message contained in the exception that has been caught?  Do you know if the request is making to the server?  Have you looked in the relevant log files, if any?  I haven't used CGI in forever, so I really don't even know what to ask in terms of troubleshooting that side.  I'm curious why you're using CGI vs something like Flask.

Comment: You say "I am not sure how to catch HTTPRequest in python".  If you're writing a CGI script, then "catching the request"  should be done behind the scene by the server that is serving your CGI script.  Do you have any CGI code working yet...any test cases that run?  Or, have you got a little CGI code but no idea how to host it or how it really works?  What I'm wondering is if you want to be using CGI in the first place.

Comment: Thing is, I can't seem to get the data using "cgi.FieldStorage()" from server side. and sending data via ajax isn't sending data for some reason.

Comment: #Update: Output error is fixed, however the output shows none in terms of data that I should receive from the input field.

Comment: How are you hosting your CGI script?  Can you be a little more precise about what you see happening.  So you click the button on your web page, and what happens?  You say "output shows none".  What does that mean exactly?  What output?  Are you seeing any behavior at all on the server side?  The more information you can give, and the clearer that information is, the better the chance that someone will be able to help you get past your problem

Comment: So I am running checkpass.py in my local machine using xampp. In python script, I am receiving a form value which is send via html web page. and I am trying to print a msg that I am receiving the form value using the HTTPRequest which is showing as None in my web page. does that make sense !

Comment: you can also check the python script I have provided in the question. I am sure it will make more sense :') ...

Comment: Check updated question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

So basically in python program you would receive the data from asyncRequest.send() which is combination of your input field creating a query param which is essentially sent via  `asyncRequest.send("Query Param");` Then using the variable name used in JS you would get value within your python script.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Login(Async)</title>
    </head>
    <script>
            function callCheckPass(){
                var username = document.querySelector("#user").value;
                var pwd = document.querySelector("#pass").value;
    
                asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                asyncRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", eve=>{
                    if(asyncRequest.readyState == 4){
                        document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML = asyncRequest.responseText;
                    }
                });
                asyncRequest.open("POST", "../../cgi-bin/checkpass.cgi", true);
                asyncRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                asyncRequest.send("username=" + username + "&" + "pwd=" + pwd);
    
            }
        </script>
    <body>
        <h1> Please Login </h1>
        User Name<br>
        <input type="text" id="user" ><br>
        Password<br>
        <input type="password" id="pass" ><br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="callCheckPass()"> Login </button>
        <p id="contentArea"> </p>
        
    </body>
        
    </html>
```

//Python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python //path to your python.exe

import cgi
import cgitb
import csv

cgitb.enable()


#instance of Field Storage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

#get data from fields.
user = form.getvalue('username') // username -> the variable used from JS, which is essential to get value. For some reason this worked for me
pwd = form.getvalue("pwd")

print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("<html>")
print("<head><title> Test </title> </head>")
print("<body> <h1>")
print(form) // data printed in your web application.
print("</h1> </body>")
print("</html>")
```